# added shell script to sudoers still getting permission denied

Tags: sudo, nagios, nrpe

I don't understand this?  Other uses of sudo work fine.

```
[oracle@o plugins]$ su
Password: 
[root@ plugins]# su nrpe
bash-3.2$ /home/oracle/obiee/instances/instance1/bifoundation/OracleBIApplication/coreapplication/setup/bi-init.sh
bash: /home/oracle/obiee/instances/instance1/bifoundation/OracleBIApplication/coreapplication/setup/bi-init.sh: Permission denied
bash-3.2$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for nrpe on this host:
    env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR
    LS_COLORS MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE LC_COLLATE
    LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC
    LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET
    XAUTHORITY"

Runas and Command-specific defaults for nrpe:


User nrpe may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL) NOPASSWD:
    /home/oracle/obiee/instances/instance1/bifoundation/OracleBIApplication/coreapplication/setup/bi-init.sh
bash-3.2$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
chmod +x /home/oracle/obiee/instances/instance1/bifoundation/OracleBIApplication/coreapplication/setup/bi-init.sh
```

The script needs to be set to 'executable' before you can actually execute it. It's to stop people executing random text files and potentially making a hash of their system.

Another problem is permissions above the script. You need to ensure the directories the scripts reside in are readable by world/the user you want to be able to.

Comment: it's set to 755

Comment: Then it's because your use can't access the directory the file resides in.

Comment: i got it.  I thought only the file needed the right permissions.